# Deserialize JSON with '@' in attribute name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON-object that contains an attribute named @id:

```
{"@id": "231"}
```

In my object i tried both:

```
[DataMember(Name = "@id")]
public string id { get; set; }
```

and

```
public string @id { get; set; }
```

but when i deserialize with json.net the id always gets null:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObc>(jsonString);
```

How can i deserialize the @id attribute?

Comment: try `JsonProperty(Name = "@id")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this -

```
class Root{
   [JsonProperty("@id")]
   public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Test -

```
var json = "{'@id': '231'}";
var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
Console.WriteLine(t.id); //231
```

Comment: I think better leave quotes like they are in question (not replace with single quotes), to not make impression that problem is in quotes.

Comment: yes. But I needed to make a valid string for the fiddle.

Comment: You can escape quotes: var json = "{\"@id\": \"231\"}" (in fiddle also).

Answer (score 2):

Changing `DataMember` to `JsonProperty` helps indeed, but if you still want to use `DataMember` - just decorate your class itself with `DataContract` attribute (that is what you probably forgot to do):

```
[DataContract]
class YourClass {
    [DataMember(Name = "@id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```